# My Media Library is broken across all my subsites

Tags: multisite, media, media-library

After installing a bad beta plugin, my Media Library is broken across all my sub-sites.

I’ve set my upload directory under Sites > domain.com > Edit Site > Settings > Upload Path to `wp-content/blogs.dir/1` (it’s an early install of WP MU)

I can upload an image to the Media Library, and the file is inserted into:

`http://billpetro.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2018/3/image.jpg`

However, the Media Library features the new image file, but:

1. There is no thumbnail, or it’s broken
2. When I open the image file says that it’s located at `http://billpetro.com/files/2018/3/image.jpg`
3. I cannot edit/crop the image file

   - Image files that I upload and use from `http://domain.com/wp-content/uploads` work fine
   - If I move files out of `http://billpetro.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/…` to `wp-content/uploads` they work fine.
   - I’ve tried Force Regenerate Thumbnails, no joy
   - I’ve commended out, in `wp-config.php` the line: `/*define( 'UPLOADS', 'wp-content/uploads');*/`
   - Security on blogs.dir is 755.